# Cyclic dependency, node was:"password" in yup

Tags: reactjs, react-native, formik, yup

I got the above error. Don't know what happened to the object. My object below.

```
export const loginValidator = yup.object({
  login: yup.string().when('password', {
    is: (v) => v < 9999 && v > 999,
    then: yup.string().required('Phone No is required').matches(phoneRegExp, 'Must be 10 digits'),
    otherwise: yup.string().email().required('Email is required'),
  }),
  password: yup.string().when('login', {
    is: (m) => phoneRegExp.test(m),
    then: yup
      .string()
      .required('Pin is Required')
      .matches(/^[0-9]+$/, 'Must be only digits')
      .min(5, 'Must be exactly 5 digits')
      .max(5, 'Must be exactly 5 digits'),
    otherwise: yup.string().required('password is required'),
  }),
});
```

Error I got

```
Error: Cyclic dependency, node was:"password"
```

whats going wrong with this
Thanks !!

Comment: It is cyclic dependency because your password is dependent on login and your login is dependent on password .

Comment: I assume that login cannot require password when password requires login

Comment: What is the solution for this

Answer (score 7):

To avoid Cyclic dependency have to add these values to the yup.

```
[['login', 'password']]
```

example,

```
export const loginValidator = yup.object().shape(
  {
    login: yup.string().when('password', {
      is: (v) => v < 100000,
      then: yup.string().required('Phone No is required').matches(phoneRegExp, 'Must be 10 digits'),
      otherwise: yup.string().email().required('Email is required'),
    }),
    password: yup.string().when('login', {
      is: (m) => phoneRegExp.test(m),
      then: yup
        .string()
        .required('Pin is Required')
        .matches(/^[0-9]+$/, 'Must be only digits')
        .min(5, 'Must be exactly 5 digits')
        .max(5, 'Must be exactly 5 digits'),
      otherwise: yup.string().required('password is required'),
    }),
  },
  [['login', 'password']]
);
```